# MongoDB SocketTimeoutException occurs even though value is set to as high as 20s with write concern set to acknowledged?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

So we have mongodb sharded setup that uses mongos to route queries to the appropriate shards. Earlier the value for socket timeout was unchanged, so it was the default infinite. We had been seeing some of our threads block for a long time on certain queries which we wanted to avoid, so we initially set the timeout to 5s. This caused quite a few `SocketTimeoutException`s to arise.

```
ERROR pool-83-thread-23 Error while writing to mongos router
com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Operation on server 127.0.0.1:27013 failed
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.doOperation(DBTCPConnector.java:217) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.receiveWriteCommandMessage(DBCollectionImpl.java:491) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.writeWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:430) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insertWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:387) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:186) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:165) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:93) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:78) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:120) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar:na]
```

We then increased the timeout to 20s but the issue still persists, though less frequently. What confuses us even more is the fact that our statsd counters tell us that typically all our write operations complete in under 15ms under peak load on our application. We have the write concern set to acknowledged. Is there something we are missing? Something else taken into account while timing out the threads on read/write operations? Or something with the java driver? (we are using 2.12.4 for it).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting problem, though it belongs to http://dba.stackexchange.com Voting to migrate.

Comment: We might be able to help you when you tell us what query you are performing, what indexes you have and how your data is structured. Otherwise, try https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: There is an issue in MongoDB jira logs. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1029 but they stated that this is working as designed. Can you have a look ?